# Passing Vec<String> from Rust to char** in C

Tags: rust, libc, unsafe, execvp

I've been trying to write a shell in Rust that links directly to the `libc` library. I've used a `Vec<String>` to hold the arguments to be passed to `execvp()`, but it seems that my conversion to `char **` has not been successful. Upon execution, all the parameters became null strings.

Here's the piece of code involved.

```
fn safe_execvp(path: String, argv: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), i32> {
    unsafe {
        let c_path = CString::new(path.as_str()).unwrap();
        let mut c_argv_vec = Vec::new();
        for arg in &argv {
            let c_arg = CString::new(arg.as_str()).unwrap().as_ptr();
            c_argv_vec.push(c_arg);
        }
        c_argv_vec.push(std::ptr::null());
        match execvp(c_file.as_ptr(), c_argv_vec.as_ptr()) {
            num => Err(num),
        }
    }
}
```

`execvp` is the C library function defined as `fn execvp(file: *const i8, argv: *const*const i8) -> i32;`.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Is it because the memory for the arguments were released before calling `execvp()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating `CString` instances and immediately fetching a pointer. Consequently, as you well guessed, ownership of this string was dropped prematurely. This is similar to returning a reference to a local instance, except that since pointers do not retain lifetime information, this case does not trigger a compilation error.

The solution to your problem is to retain the owned C-style strings during the function's scope, and produce a pointer to pointers of the same content separately.

```
let cstr_argv: Vec<_> = argv.iter()
        .map(|arg| CString::new(arg.as_str()).unwrap())
        .collect();

let mut p_argv: Vec<_> = cstr_argv.iter() // do NOT into_iter()
        .map(|arg| arg.as_ptr())
        .collect();

p_argv.push(std::ptr::null());

let p: *const *const c_char = p_argv.as_ptr();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b839923d94354b127097724db17d9562&version=stable&backtrace=0).

See also: [CString::new().unwrap().as_ptr() gives empty *const c_char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52174925/1233251)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should've kept the `CString`s in a vector.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you read [the documentation for `CString::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) again:

> **WARNING**
>
> It is your responsibility to make sure that the underlying memory is not
>   freed too early. For example, the following code will cause undefined
>   behavior when `ptr` is used inside the `unsafe` block:
>
> ```
> # #![allow(unused_must_use)]
> use std::ffi::{CString};
>
> let ptr = CString::new("Hello").expect("CString::new failed").as_ptr();
> unsafe {
>     // `ptr` is dangling
>     *ptr;
> }
> ```
>
> This happens because the pointer returned by `as_ptr` does not carry any
>   lifetime information and the [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) is deallocated immediately after
>   the `CString::new("Hello").expect("CString::new failed").as_ptr()` expression is evaluated.
>   To fix the problem, bind the `CString` to a local variable:
>
> ```
> # #![allow(unused_must_use)]
> use std::ffi::{CString};
>
> let hello = CString::new("Hello").expect("CString::new failed");
> let ptr = hello.as_ptr();
> unsafe {
>     // `ptr` is valid because `hello` is in scope
>     *ptr;
> }
> ```
>
> This way, the lifetime of the `CString` in `hello` encompasses
>   the lifetime of `ptr` and the `unsafe` block.

You are doing exactly what the documentation says not to do.

Comment: Thanks! I read that part but didn't realize I made the mistake it warned not to.